# Can you change or create your own ending story?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

So many of us know that when you beat the ender-dragon you basically win the game, and that a long story is displayed along with the ending credits.

[image: Ending credits]

Is there a way to portray a different story when this happens or create your own for multiplayer use?  Maybe a plugin is out there somewhere.

Comment: It is unclear what you want to do with this. Do you want to modify your own game, or create a map or mod for other people to play?

Comment: I'll be honest, I would like both.  But I was leaning towards map for other people.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be edited, but you don't need a mod to do so.

This story can be found in a text file, found in `assets/minecraft/texts/end.txt`. Using a resource pack can change the appearance of it, but as far as I am aware, you can change the text to whatever you want simply by re-writing the file.

The [Technical Details](https://minecraft.wiki/w/End_Poem#Technical_details) on the wiki have a bit more information about the text formatting.

---

If you want to use it for multiplayer games, you will need to make a mod pack and include the file(s) in that mod pack, to be installed in each player's games. You could even change the Credits (found in `assets/minecraft/texts/credits.txt`) and add yourself in as a mod creator!

Comment: Your post is very useful, but I'd like to keep the "answered" open, to see if there is a multiplayer way for it's use.

Comment: All you should really need to do in that case is make a mod (yeah I know I said you didn't lol) and include the file(s) in the mod pack

Comment: Great quick response, I think I can make good use of this info.

Comment: Glad I could help out

Comment: Does multiplayer changing require a modpack? Or did you mean resource pack, because the /assets/... Seems to be something to be put in a resource pack.

Comment: @Judge2020 yes, this is primarily changed in the texturepack, however, I'm mods unique blocks are given their own textures, so similarly, this can be added as part of a mod in the same way.